# Python multilingual SpeechRecognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I have a speech recognition in Python project. So, I need it to recognize 5 languages.

My code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer() 
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
    print(r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU en-US de-DE fr-FR es-ES"))
```

It recognizes only english and russian speech. Please help.

Comment: You need to provide more info if you want people to help :) Otherwise how are we supposed to know about `r` in your single line quote ? Is it an instance of `speech_recognition.Recogniser` from https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/ ? Etc, etc... Please provide move code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the Google Speech Recognition API, which you are calling in the call to `recognize_google()` works on **single-language** models. That is, it will only accent the *first* language code that you pass to it. It is expecting audio to be in a single language.

What you're describing, with speech in five different languages, is called *code-switching*, and the speech recognition model needs to be build specifically for code switching. AFAIK, none of the cloud speech recognition providers currently offers code switching models, and if they did, five different languages would be ... unlikely.

Can you split the audio so that you're sending one language at a time?